# filestream not working in Dll

Tags: c++, dll

i have exported an global filestream say xlog from an dll say xlogger,

i initilize xlog in  dll process attach macro , and close in detach.

now i am adding reference of this dll in my other projects in same solution as below.

```
testDll_1 -> add reference xlogger ,
testDll_2 -> add reference xlogger ,
testDll_2 -> add reference xlogger ,
exe -> add reference xlogger ,
```

my problem is xlog<<"message" works only in the xlogger dll and exe however no log is generated from inside dll. 
here i am using windows 7 enterprise with vs 2010 professional,

am i loading multiple copyes of dll in above testdll projects ? or same copy(single copy)is getting used ? or how can i resolve this problem ?.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What runtime library do you use? static library, or DLL?

Comment: i am using dll, i tried code in vs 2012 it works well ,i am little confuse , surely i need to do little more work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok its my mistake
actually i open file stream in dll_proc_attach, & i am closing in dll_proc_detach,
the problem was the stream is getting close somehow.
so now i wrote seprate functions to open and close stream and code is working fine.
thanks all for replies.